# restore my users

Tags: support, status-completed

please advice

my user not appears in the serverfault site so I can’t back and ask question
I have two users (both users are my user) and actually I want to merge them because I lost those users

user:105707

user:109961

thx for the support

Comment: I have merged your accounts together user:105707 is the master account now and is associated with your yahoo email account.

Comment: thx allot for your help

Answer (score 5):

I have merged your accounts together user:105707 is the master account now and is associated with your yahoo email address. Please consider becoming a registered user.